# Best Practices for DRY Data Annotation in ASP MVC ViewModels and EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, data-annotations, dry

I have the following working system and looking for ways to make it DRY:

```
public class EMailMetaData
{
  [Display(Prompt="myemail@mydomain.com"])
  public string Data;
}
public class PhoneMetaData
{
  [Display(Prompt="+1 (123) 456-7890"])
  public string Data;
}
public class AddressMetaData
{
  [Display(Prompt="Central st. W., St Francisco, USA"])
  public string Data;
}
// 7 more metadata templates

public class ContactVM
{
  [Required]
  public string DataLabel { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill in the data field")]
  public string Data { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(EmailMetaData))]
EmailVM : ContactVM
{
}
[MetadataType(typeof(PhoneMetaData))]
PhoneVM : ContactVM
{
}
[MetadataType(typeof(AddressMetaData))]
AddressVM : ContactVM
{
}
// 7 more contact view models
```

Controller is obviously initializes them with right content and in the view I run over the foreach loop of ContactVMs having TemplateEditor for every one of contacts: EmailVM.cshtml, PhoneVM.cshtml, AddressVM.cshtml UrlVM.cshtml etc.

The main view looks (omitting all the setup and details like this:

```
@model ContactsVM
foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => contact)
}
```

and under EditorTemplates

```
@model EmailVM
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataLabel)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data)
<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataLabel)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)
```

... and obviously few more editor templates for every view model I have defined.

So in simple words - very similar contact types with minor differences in watermarking, naming, validation, but essentially all strings and all have the same fields (address is one long string rather than struct, same for all of them).

My question is not specific for watermarking, it can be any of properties - name, description, prompt etc.

```
[Display(Name="name", Description="description", Prompt="prompt")]
```

Its all pretty much working and showing right labels, watermarks for each, but it seems like huge DRY violation since all the template editors are exactly the same except the model type. What I show is here simplification to concentrate on the problem at hand, main view and editor templates are significantly more complicated that what you see here, so duplication is tremendous.

Can any of you suggest better way of making it not duplicating so much code please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It is blunt solution but much simpler than those suggested and most important requires least duplication compared to straightforward solution (although not too elegant considering we're in object oriented world):

1. Define one view with base class (or interface, however you define it) as your model.
2. In the view cast the model variable to the right class
3. In the view, use the cast variable rather than the model

So Contact.cshtml will look like this:

```
@model ContactVM
@* Do tons of stuff that is the same between views (not depending on data annotation) *@
@Html.Partial("_ContactDataAnnotation", Model)
@* Continue doing lots of stuff that is the same between all those classes
```

Calling Contact.cshtml editor template will go in the following manner (thanks Serg):

```
@foreach (var c in Model.Contacts)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => c, "Contact")
}
```

The partial view that is dedicated to only show the right data annotations _ContactDataAnnotation.cshtml will look like this:

```
@using <My Model Namespace>
@model ContactVM
@switch (Model.GetType().Name)
{
  case "EmailVM":
    EmailVM e = Model as EmailVM;
    @Html.EditorFor(model => e.DataLabel)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => e.Data)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => e.DataLabel)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => e.Data)
    break;
  case "PhoneVM":
    PhoneVM p = Model as PhoneVM;
    @Html.EditorFor(model => p.DataLabel)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => p.Data)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => p.DataLabel)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => p.Data)
    break;
  // same thing 7 more times for all children of ContactVM, since MVC does not applying polymorphism to data annotations UNFORTUNATELY
  default:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataLabel)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataLabel)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)
  }
```

By this the duplication will only exist in places that is required, rather than having the same editor template duplicated 10 times with different names and model classes.

I know it contradicts the title of the question "best practices", but unfortunately this is the easiest and most minimalistic way to go. Other solutions, as Serg pointed out, are way too complex and require deep MVC infrastructure intervention, which I don't like spending time on, as well as having prompts and tooltips injected rather than defined in data annotation, which appears to be a standard way of decorating and validating your models.

I consider my solution to be a workaround MVC limitation of lacking polymorphism for data annotations.

Comment: There's one thing I'd like to note here. You say that DataAnnotations appear to be a standard way of decorating and validaing your models. They're not. They're just the way there is in the box. MVC is extensible not without reason, and the reason is exactly the cases like yours. I also must add that your model in a sense contradicts to "standard way" of defining viewmodel and is somewhere in the vicinity of Dynamic Data.

Comment: Agreed. However some things are intuitively expected and aren't delivered. Exactly like in this case. I am not doing anything extraordinary by having hierarchy of classes for view models and expect them to behave like classes in OO way including their data annotations. 
I am working on improving the solution above by using reflection instead of having huge and barely extensible switch statement (which in turn I've come to hate just be looking at it). Update will be posted later

Answer (score 2):

(I am adding another answer because that's entirely different approach to the problem here)

The structure of both viewmodels and views are suggesting that we're looking at some meta-meta-meta-data, the pattern which I come to hate, sorry.

Let's at first take a straightforward approach and find out what *is* our model. I suppose it's something like this:

```
public class ContactsVM
{
    [Required]
    public string EmailLabel {get;set;}

    [Display(Prompt="myemail@mydomain.com"])
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill in the data field")]
    public string Email {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string PhoneLabel {get;set;}

    [Display(Prompt="+1 (123) 456-7890"])
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill in the data field")]
    public string Phone {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public string AddressLabel {get;set;}

    [Display(Prompt="Central st. W., St Francisco, USA"])
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill in the data field")]
    public string Address {get;set;}

    // 7 more property pairs
}
```

Plain, simple, straightforward, easy to understand. Yes, it would require some code duplication in view (meaning two `EditorFor`s followed by `ValidationMessage`), but in my experience that's not a problem because in most cases one day you'll have to somehow tweak this code for one (and only one) property. If you don't like that - now, there's one more solution:

```
@* let's assume that props is a string[] holding meaningful property names, e.g "Email", "Phone", "Address". You can even get it dynamically from reflection
@foreach (var property in props)
{
    @Html.Editor(property + "Label") @Html.Editor(property)
    <br />
    @Html.Validation(property + "Label") @Html.Validation(property)
}
```

**Update on dynamic models**

Now, all of above won't work if we have variable number of data-items in model (which I come to hate even more now when I work with this on daily basis), so now we have to cope with that too. What we try to achieve is in fact, same view code as above, but now our model will not contain those properties. All the magic lies in two things.

1. We turn our model into something `Dictionary`-like, containing string keys pointing to string data. How we populate it, does not matter.
2. We provide our own `ModelMetadataProvider` which will override default behavior for our model class with following:

   1. given model instance, it will respond to `GetProperties` by enumerating over aforementioned dictionary, and creating `ModelMetadata` from those string
   2. each created `ModelMetadata` should contain ModelValue corresponding to value from our dictionary
   3. all the other properties of `ModelMetadata` are filled according to our wishes (we don't need DataAnnotations no more, we will inject all values in provider)

That takes a lot of work and a bit of trying, but in the end it works, I'd say from my experience. But I wouldn't recommend this *overall* design approach, as it requires... you've already seen amount of work and it's just a beginning.

Comment: You've got it right, Serg (not with VM, but with variable data-items in model). I am trying to replicate gmail contact behaviour - dynamic amount of anything plus adding/deleting any new label and data item to that Brownian Motion . So the static model won't work, unfortunately. Otherwise I wouldn't have the question. BTW, was playing with ModelMetaProvider - successfully overwrote it, but stuck with how to move on from there - not obvious at all. I guess I will just duplicate the 10 editor templates and be done with it. Much time waisted. Thanks for help!

Comment: I've added a bit on dynamic models to my answer.

Comment: Serg. Having trying that for some time - yes, I get results, but it never answers my original question: no matter how I manipulate data annotations inside the `ModelMetadataProvider` - it doesn't affect and cause the view to resolve data annotations or on-the-fly injected values into right object instance. It always goes by the `@model` type and nothing else. So: thanks for the effort, unfortunately, no cigar.

Comment: @DisplayName that means that you have not properly injected your metadata provider. I'm using this approach in production code.

Comment: Can you please provide a piece of sample code just showing "how to", please?

Comment: @DisplayName I'll try to, but (as it usually goes with asp.net mvc) it consists of several next-to-unrelated classes, so it's not a piece, but a patchwork.

Comment: While injecting all values in provider (as opposed to data annotation), you still are creating humongous switch: in case its Email it will be injection of certain values, in case its Address it will be injection of other values, in case of Phone etc etc etc. What makes it any better than my switch in the view then? (THe one I marked as the answer) In my switch I at least have all definitions on view model in one place, while in case of provider it seems to me much harder to even understand and maintain. Please give your perspective. Thanks

Comment: I don't like *any* logic in view. And metadata provider allows doing that based on dictionary and several different classes, not `switch`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15086/discussion-between-display-name-and-serg-rogovtsev)

Answer (score 1):

(Your problem stems from the fact that your viewmodels are not specific, but a kind of "one generic solution to every problem out there".)

But still, there's an quite easy solution: create one *named* editor template for all your types, having `ContactVM` as model type, and use `@Html.EditorFor(m => contact, "YourTemplateName")`.

Comment: Serg, thanks for the response. Very elegant, yet not solving my DRY problem: still I have to define 1 editor template per 1 class ... unless I am missing something? Thanks

Comment: If it's not then I don't understand what's your problem.

Comment: My view models (email, url, address, phone etc) are only different by data annotation, nothing else. In order to get this annotation to work I figured I need to **create 1 editor template per class**, which I hate to do and which is the problem.
I'd like to have 1 editor template what would based on model class  (child of ContactVM) display the right data annotation and right validation as per that class.
I found no way to do it and asking community if there's better way than just duplicating everything multiple times.
Or should I define view models differently - open for suggestions. 
Thanks!

Comment: I have already said how to create one editor template for all your classes derived from `ContactVM`. Have you tried it?

Comment: not sure I understood your approach first time. I create one editortemplate called ContactVM and then call it in for loop using @Html.EditorFor(m => contact, "ContactVM")? But in this case even if I don't define all typed templates, but just one ContactVM doesn't show right data annotations, but only defined on ContactVM class - I tried it before. And again, maybe you meant something else that I missed. If so - please explain.

Comment: That's what you should've said in the first place. The easiest solution to *that* is to override `ModelMetadataProvider` so it takes into account runtime model class.

Comment: Serg. can you please shed little more light on how to do that? (you talking to relatively newbie). Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a pretty long story (part of which I don't know for myself). I suppose you can start from [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=715) or [there](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/).

Comment: Thanks Serg. I'll explore this one and once its working as expected will mark yours as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create Interface, like

```
public interface IContactData
{
string Data{get; set;};
.
.
.
}
```

The implement that interface in your classes

```
public class EMailMetaData : IContactData
{
  [Display(Prompt="myemail@mydomain.com"])
  public string Data{get; set;};
...
}
public class PhoneMetaData  : IContactData
{
  [Display(Prompt="+1 (123) 456-7890"])
  public string Data{get; set;};
....
}
```

And in your editor template(one for all) use

```
@model IContactData
```

Comment: As far as I know, it won't work, at least out of the box - default `ModelMetadataProvider` will look at annotations on the *interface*, not implementation.